# statistics by rectangle (raster image)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, spatial-statistics

I have a shp file with some rectangles and I want to extract statistics within these areas from a raster image. I prefer ArcMap 9.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your task could be done easily by using Zonal Statistics tool of Spatial Analyst extension.

Comment: +1.  This assumes the rectangles do not overlap, though.  If they do overlap, you need to loop over the rectangles (or over subsets of disjoint rectangles).

Comment: For versions of ArcGIS prior to 10, Hawth's tools has Zonal Statistics ++ which deals with overlapping polygons, give it a shot.  http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/zonalstats.php

Answer (score 4):

As a free alternative, SAGA GIS contains a module that may do what you want (Grid Statistics for Polygons).
http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_modules_doc/shapes_grid/index.html

Comment: +1.  "Grid statistics for polygons" appears only to obtain a limited set of quantiles (5%, 10%, ..., 95%).  However, the ability to obtain *any* quantile (apart from the median) does not exist in ArcGIS, so it's good to know about this capability.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use GRASS for zonal statistics. From [doc page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.statistics.html):

**r.statistics** is a tool to analyse exploratory statistics of a "cover layer" according to how it intersects with objects in a "base layer". A variety of standard statistical measures are possible (called "zonal statistics" in some GIS).

The available methods are the following:

- distribution
- average
- mode
- median
- average deviation
- standard deviation
- variance
- skewness
- kurtosis
- minimum
- maximum
- sum

Answer (score 3):

If you need more complex statistics or a free alternative (compared to spatial analyst), you can use [raster](http://crantastic.org/packages/raster) package in [R](http://www.r-project.org/). From which you can extract pretty much any statistic you can imagine.